# Read JSON file from the Controller and display as <li> using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My employee.json file is on the same directory as my controller.

This is the data on my json file:

```
["John", "Clark"]
```

On the controller I have:

```
.controller('EmployeeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('employee.json').then(function (res) {
    $scope.contents = res.data;
    });
 });
```

On the template I have:

```
<div>
 <label class="control-label">Identify yourself:</label>
 <select ng-model="market.name">
   <option ng-repeat="content in contents" value="{{content}}">{{content}} </option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this is not working? My dropdownlist displays nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put to work this way:
On the client side, I created a new folder (service) to have the service called jasonFactory on the app/script/service/jasonFactory.js.
The code for the service is:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .factory('jsonFactory', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
      getOtherStuff: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
          httpPromise = $http.get('data/Employee.json');

        httpPromise.then(function (response) {
          deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

Also, I created a new folder (data) to have the json file called Employee.json on the app/data/Employee.json.
The content for the json file is:

```
{"names": [
{"name": "John"}
]}
```

Then, I added some code on the controller file app/script/controllers/usedController.js.
The code for the controller is:

```
.controller('AddCtrl', function (jsonFactory) {
 $scope.otherStuff = {};
    jsonFactory.getOtherStuff()
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.otherStuff = response.data.names;
        alert($scope.otherStuff);
      }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert("test");
      });
});
```

Also, the template goes like this:

```
<select>
      <option ng-repeat="stuff in otherStuff" value="{{stuff.name}}">          {{stuff.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that at the time the promise gets resolved, the digest cycle has already ran, perhaps using `$scope.$apply` solves your issues as it will run the digest cycle again:

```
$http.get('employee.json').then(function (res) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.contents = res.data;
    });
});
```

As per the comment, it seems the problem relies in the url of the json you are trying to retrieve, did you try adding a slash at the beginning of the url to make it relative to your domain?

```
$http.get('/employee.json') //Note i've added "/" at the beginning.
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to implement your way and variations of it, but it didn't work. Also, I used alert("test") just below $scope.contents = res.data; to check if the function was being executed, but it didn't pop up the alert message. This made me think that the code within the second curly braces is not running and I don't know the reason.

Comment: This is the error I am getting:                                                         Cannot GET /employee.json
404
{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse"[null],"url":"employee.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}} 
Not Found                                                                                                                         - Do you have any advice to resolve it?

Comment: Check my edit, the problem is the url from where you are retrieving the json file.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I tried with "/" and "./" in the beginning, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
.controller('EmployeeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('employee.json').success(function (res) {
    $scope.contents = response.data;
  });
});
```

Also make sure the data in the JSON file is formatted properly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to implement your way and variations of it, but it didn't work. Also, I used alert("test") just below $scope.contents = response.data; to check if the function was being executed, but it didn't pop up the alert message. This made me think that the code within the second curly braces is not running and I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, Maybe you were trying to be general, but you json file isn't an object. You might want to make sure your JSON is in the {'label': 'info'} format. Then, that response only returns the whole json as an object as 'res'.

So if your json had {name: mike, job: ninja},

```
$http.get(file).then(function(res){
    var data = res; //object
    var name = data.name; //property
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to implement your way and variations of it, but it didn't work. Also, I used alert("test") just below var name = data.name; //property to check if the function was being executed, but it didn't pop up the alert message. This made me think that the code within the curly braces is not running and I don't know the reason.

Comment: I did what you said:                                                  $http.get('employee.json'). then(function(response) {
      alert("test");
    }, function(response) {
      alert(response);
    });                                                    The result is: The alert message is displaying [object Object] instead of "test". It seems that an error is occurring.

Comment: I did this and received an error:       $scope.contents = [];
    // Simple GET request example :
    $http.get('employee.json'). then(function(response) {
      alert("test");
    }, function(response) {
      alert(response);
      $scope.contents = response;});                                                                                                         -The error is saying: can not get /employee.json 404 {"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse"[null],"url":"employee.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}} Not Found

Comment: Just to facilitate the visualization of the error:                                     This is the error I am getting:                                                            Cannot GET /employee.json
404
{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse"[null],"url":"employee.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}} 
Not Found                                                                                                                         - Do you have any advice to resolve it?

Comment: Where did you put that file in your directory

Comment: Make sure that if you use just the file name e.g. employee.json with no / or other slashes, then keep the file right with the index file, I think your root directory

Comment: I put the file in the same directory where I have the controller's .js file.

Comment: well is that in a folder that is not in your angular app folder? if so you might have to /controllerfolder/employee.json

Comment: The folder is in the app folder. On my index.html I am using this script: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Do you think that this could be the reason, because I am not using the angular.min?

Comment: not using the angular.min is not the problem. give me your folder structure.

If you want to use $http.get('employee.json') put the file in your app folder and not the controller folder. When you search for anything, it usually searches from the root

Comment: #WebApp root folder                                                                                      -client folder                                                                                                 -   -app folder having the index.html file                                                                                         -        -scripts folder having the app.js file                                                  -            -controllers folder                                                                        -server folder

Comment: WebApp/client/app/scripts/controllers                                                               WebApp/server                                                                                                WebApp/client/app/index.html                                                                               WebApp/client/app/scripts/app.js                                                                 WebApp/client/app/scripts/controllers

Comment: Then try /webapp/client/app/scripts/controllers/employee.json or /scripts/controllers/employee.json or move the file, there's only so many possible combos

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use the fs module from node to read the file? I am asking because I used successfully it on the server side to read a local json file. However, It didn't work on the client side

Comment: yes you can use fs.module to read it, if you are using express, you can expose the data through a route.

Comment: Do you have any orientation how I can do that? I did this on the server side, and It worked. However, It didn't work on the client side.                    - var fs = require('fs');
    var names = fs.readFileSync('./names.json', "utf8");

Comment: For something like express: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html
but I don't know how you are creating your server side framework.
For express, you can get the results and then use res.json(results) for consumption by the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you move your file to the www folder it should be alright. Worked with me.
Or where your index.html is.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but it didn't work. Trying to implement other ways I have this error. Do you have any advice to resolve it? This is the error I am getting:                                                                          Cannot GET /employee.json
404
{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse"[null],"url":"employee.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}} 
Not Found

Comment: Maybe if you get the error message, it can help. Did you test it with an online url?

Comment: I did not test with a url. The error message is the one starting with "Cannot GET" on my first comment to you. Do you know if it is possible to use the fs module from node to read the file. I am asking because I used successfully it on the server side to read a local json file. However, It didn't work on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **(key, value)** on repeat:

Look that jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/segevojibe/edit?html,js,output

```
<select ng-model="market.name">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, content) in contents" value="{{content}}">{{content}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the jsbin. I had success with this implementation, but I need the array with names coming from a local employee.json file. I am not having success reading the file's content. Could you update the jsbin reading the names from a file within the controllers' directory, please?

Comment: I had made a code to read local files... I will to find and, if I found, I can update the jsbin.

Comment: Well, I have not my old fonts... But I found the method I used: readFile()... it exists on young navigators, not on old IE7. Take a look on this article: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/03/building-a-filereader-service-for-angularjs-the-service.aspx